# How make this query response time faster

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am fetching latest date record (single) among the 100k records. I want the query response time faster.

I tried with two solutions mentioned below both taking much time to response.

Solution 1:

```
DetachedCriteria maxDate = DetachedCriteria.forClass(EventData.class);
    maxDate.add(Restrictions.eq("device", device));
    maxDate.setProjection(Projections.max("dateTime"));

Criteria eventDataCreCriteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EventData.class, "e").createAlias("e.device", "d").createAlias("d.deviceList", "dl");

eventDataCreCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("device", device));
eventDataCreCriteria.add(Property.forName("dateTime").eq(maxDate)); //line 1
eventDataCreCriteria.setMaxResults(1);
EventData eventData = (EventData) eventDataCreCriteria.uniqueResult();
```

Solution 2:

```
Criteria eventDataCreCriteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EventData.class, "e").createAlias("e.device", "d").createAlias("d.deviceList", "dl");

eventDataCreCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("device", device));
eventDataCreCriteria.addOrder(Order.desc("dateTime")); //line 2
eventDataCreCriteria.setMaxResults(1);
EventData eventData = (EventData) eventDataCreCriteria.uniqueResult();
```

if i remove line 1&2 from both solution then it start responding too fast but then not getting latest date records.

I want just single latest date record with less response time.

Comment: ensure that you have an index on `dateTime`

Comment: You want to take a look at the sql and the related query plan the database generates for it. How many records and what response time are we actually talking about?

Comment: @ScaryWombat is it possible to add index now on existing table without loosing the records

Comment: @second i am saying in general way as table contain lots of records and query response time too faster if remove line 1 and 2 but it takes higher time if execute with these lines

Comment: If you remove the `sorting` from the query, it will obviously be faster, as you just stop at the first result you find, which in return will most likely not what you are looking for. Please consider adding some numbers and your sql and query plan to your question.

Comment: @jupiter yes, adding an index will not loose data, just potentially slow down the database (in all sane dbms I'm aware of)

Comment: @second thanks for reply but the things i want know is there is any other way to optimize query response time/code or it is fine enough so i have to go with it as it is

Comment: If you want to approach the problem from another angle, you should ask yourself what other informations you have available - to make the number of records that need to be sorted lower. Maybe you can estimate the time range by using some other database field (that already exists or that you need to create).

Comment: @second yes i sorted it out with other column available in tables so now getting response much faster than earlier... Thanks a lot for your help.